# Calculations on aggregated data using groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have this code from SAP HANA SQL and I need to convert it into pandas.
Is it possible in pandas?,as I have not found any example for this kind of case.
**This is a dummy code so kindly skip indentation and naming convention part.**

```
   select distinct 
   "A","B","C","D",
   to_nvarchar(sum(to_decimal("Column2"))/TO_DECIMAL(max("Column3"))) as "Column2" ,to_nvarchar(min(to_date("Date",'YYYYMMDD')),'YYYYMMDD') as "Date",

   from :Var1 
   group by 
  "A","B","C","D";
```

I tried:

```
df4["Column2"]=df4.Column2.astype(int)    
 df4["Column2"]=df4["Column2"]/df4["Column3"].groupby(["A","B","C","D"]).agg({'
 Colum‌​n2': 'sum','Colum‌​n3':'max'}).reset_index()
 df5=df4[["A","B","C","D","Colum‌​n3"]]
```

I am getting KeyError "A"

```
 INPUT TABLE:
A   B     C     D     Column2   Column3  date
BOE MT1 TYPE1   50000      45   5       20111231
BOE MT1 TYPE1   50000      35   1       20101201
BOE MT1 TYPE1   50001      85   5       20110721
BOE MT1 TYPE4   50000      25   5       20110718
BOE MT1 TYPE4   50001      90   5       20111212





 A    B  C        D    Column2            date
BOE MT1 TYPE1   50000   16  <-(45+35)/5   20101201
BOE MT1 TYPE1   50001   17  <-85/5        20110721
BOE MT1 TYPE4   50000   5   <-25/5        20110718
BOE MT1 TYPE4   50001   18  <- 90/5       20111212
```

Comment: yes, it's possible. There are enough examples in the documentation to get you started : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html

Comment: for normal Min,max,sum it is possibl, but to find max/sum of 2 column and divide them,how can we perform that

Comment: to divide two columns df["C"] = df["A"].div(df["B"]) or df["C"] = df["A"]/df["B"]

Comment: I am asking about this condition.
 select distinct 
   "A","B","C","D",
 to_nvarchar(sum(to_decimal("Column2"))/TO_DECIMAL(max("Column3"))) as "Column2" ,
     from :Var1 
   group by 
  "A","B","C","D";

Comment: If you want some help, you'll have to provide some input, expected output, and what you tried and why it didn't work. We aren't here to do your assignments for you, so please understand [ask] a good question.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, I have mentioned my code, now lets see If you can help me with this.

Comment: @SarthakSrivastava We still can't, because we don't know what your dataframe looks like. Print out the first 10 columns using `df.head(10)` and then tell us what you want the expected output to look like.

Comment: @COLDSPEED done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, a `groupby` and `apply` should do it

```
out = df1.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])\
           .apply(lambda x: x.Column2.sum() / x.Column3.max())\
           .reset_index()
print(out)

     A    B      C      D     0
0  BOE  MT1  TYPE1  50000  16.0
1  BOE  MT1  TYPE1  50001  17.0
2  BOE  MT1  TYPE4  50000   5.0
3  BOE  MT1  TYPE4  50001  18.0
```

Comment: I am getting error at list().
Key error :B

also I have edited the question as I want to know how can we work for multiple calculation in pandas I am not getting any correct syntax.

Comment: @SarthakSrivastava Substitute "list(ABCD)" with the list of your first four column names.

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes I am using my column names only, how will it differentiate between different columns ABCD in List()?
eg: if column names are ->sarthak,coldspeed,stack
so it should be list('sarthakcoldspeedstack') according to your logic?

Comment: @SarthakSrivastava `list('ABCD')` translates to `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`. This worked for me, not sure why it doesn't for you. Maybe your column names have spaces in them. Print `df.columns` and check that.

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes I am using my column names only, how will it differentiate between different columns ABCD in List()?
eg: if column names are ->sarthak,coldspeed,stack
so it should be list('sarthakcoldspeedstack') according to your logic?

Comment: @SarthakSrivastava Definitely not. It must be `['sarthak', 'coldspeed', 'stack']` EXPLICITLY. Otherwise `list('sarthakcoldspeedstack')` is `['s',
 'a',
 'r',
 't',
 'h',
 'a',
 'k',
 'c',
 'o',
 'l',
 'd',
 's',
 'p',
 'e',
 'e',
 'd',
 's',
 't',
 'a',
 'c',
 'k']` which is definitely wrong.

Comment: @ColdSPEED It worked for that part, now IIUC for date part this should work like:
df4["Date"]=to_datetime(df4["Date"])
       df4.groupby(['A','B','C','D']).apply(lambda x:x.Date.min()).reset_index(name='Date')

Comment: @SarthakSrivastava I think it should work. Though I am unsure of the reset index part.

Comment: @COLDSPEED .reset_index(name='abc') is just for giving name to the output column, as in your o/p "0" is the column name, as nothing is mentioned in .reset_index()

Comment: Gotcha. That's new info to me! Anyway, glad I could help. All the best!

Comment: @COLDSPEED there is one more problem, if I have one more column "Column4" and I want to apply same logic to it,and want to display both these column, how will it work?
as I am getting error.

Comment: @COLDSPEED and 1 more thing If I have one more column in input table but i dont want to use it in groupby but want in o/p what can I do?

Comment: Set it as the index and then reset after the groupby.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153900/discussion-between-sarthak-srivastava-and-cs).

Comment: @SarthakSrivastava Sorry, I forgot to respond to this. What is your doubt exactly?? If you have a new question, won't you open a new thread? :)

Comment: Actually I was asking about you comment only"Set it as the index and then reset after the groupby", I did not understood what it means

Comment: @SarthakSrivastava If you set those columns that you want to ignore as the index, they are ignored during the groupby computation. You can use `df.set_index([....])` to do that. After groupby, call `df.reset_index()`.